# How do I count numbers inbetween variables

Tags: python

I need to write this code but I can't figure out how to get it to count the mphs over the speed limit the person goes.

```
speed = int(input("How fast where they going? (in mph) "))
limit = int(input("What is the speed limit? "))

if speed > limit:
    print("Illegal Speed!")
    if speed > 90:
        fine = 250
        for i in speed:
            fine = fine + 5
        print("Their fine is $", fine)
    else:
        fine = 50
        for i in speed:
            fine = fine + 5
        print("Their fine is $", fine)

if speed <= limit:
    print("Legal Speed")
```

Comment: I guess you want to do : ```for i in range(speed - limit)```

Comment: you really want to use for loops instead of basic multiplications ? `fine = 250 + 5*(speed - limit)`

Comment: why not just `fine = 250 + 5 *(speed-limit)`and `fine = 50 + 5 * (speed - limit)`?

Comment: For negative speeds (moving backwards) the system penalizes you for going slower. Imagine the case where `limit = -100` and `speed = -90` --> BAM! you get a fine! (speed > limit), but if your speed is -200 then you are OK :)

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki: there is also not taking time dilation into account when approaching the speed of light. But I think neither that nor your observation were part of this assignment.

Comment: Negative speed is just positive speed in the opposite direction.  The absolute value of the speed is what should be compared to the limit, which also should never be negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add 5 for every mile per hour over the speed limit, it's simply `(speed-limit)*5`

Your code results in:

```
speed = int(input("How fast where they going? (in mph) "))
limit = int(input("What is the speed limit? "))

if speed > limit:
    print("Illegal Speed!")
    if speed > 90:
        fine = 250
        adder = (speed-limit) * 5
    else:
        fine = 50
        adder = (speed-limit) * 5

    print("Their fine is $", (fine+adder))
if speed <= limit:
    print("Legal Speed")
```

Comment: the adder and the print part is the same for both fines, so you can put them outside the conditional.

Comment: Fixed @SembeiNorimaki

Answer (score 2):

Considering that what Charles commented about your intention of adding 5 for every mile per hour over the speed limit is correct, I believe this solution would be cleaner:

```
speed = int(input("How fast where they going? (in mph) "))
limit = int(input("What is the speed limit? "))

if speed > limit:

    print("Illegal Speed!")

    if speed > 90:
        fine = 250
    else:
        fine = 50

    fine += (speed - limit) * 5
    print("Their fine is $", fine)

else:

    print("Legal Speed")
```

Since the fine calculation and print are the same for both cases, it's easier to put it in a "common zone" and use the if/else just to set "fine" initial value.

Comment: This is cleaner